# Getting "Unhandled promise rejection Error: Element type is invalid: Check the render method of `PdfView`. " when using react-native-pdf package

Tags: javascript, file, react-native

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
 import Pdf from 'react-native-pdf';
 import { View } from 'react-native';
 export default class ActivityInformation extends Component {
  render() { 
   const source = {uri:'http://samples.leanpub.com/thereactnativebook-
     sample.pdf', cache: true}; 
   return(
    <View>
     <Pdf
       source={source}
       onLoadComplete={(numberOfPages, filePath)=>{
       console.log(`number of pages: ${numberOfPages}`);
        }}
       onPageChanged={(page, numberOfPages)=>{
         console.log(`current page: ${page}`);
       }}
       onError={(error)=>{
        console.log(error);
       }}
     />
   </View>
  )
 }
}
```

commands for the setup:

```
npm install react-native-pdf --save

npm install react-native-fetch-blob --save

react-native link react-native-pdf

react-native link react-native-fetch-blob
```

i am getting **"ExceptionsManager.js:71 Unhandled JS Exception: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `PdfView`."** error on iphone simulator. please suggest me any solution. or suggest me any other npm package same like this package
[image]

Comment: Can you post your full file, please? With the imports.

Comment: I have edited my code so, please suggest me the solution if you know

Comment: Did you run react-native link?

Comment: Also be sure you have react-native-fetch-blob installed